# Installing VIM in FreeBSD

Tags: unix, vim, freebsd

I'm a newbie with a fresh install of FreeBSD 10 and am trying to install VIM thusly:

```
cd /usr/ports/editors/vim && export FLAVOR=no_x11 && make install clean
```

It then gets bogged down trying to download 'libpng':

```
===>    Verifying install for png15 in /usr/ports/graphics/png
===>  Found saved configuration for png-1.5.17
===>   png-1.5.17 depends on file: /usr/local/sbin/pkg - found
=> libpng-1.5.17.tar.xz doesn't seem to exist in /usr/ports/distfiles/.
=> Attempting to fetch http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng15/1.5.17/libpng-1.5.17.tar.xz
fetch: http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng15/1.5.17/libpng-1.5.17.tar.xz: Moved Temporarily
....
=> Attempting to fetch ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/libpng-1.5.17.tar.xz
fetch: ftp://ftp.FreeBSD.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/libpng-1.5.17.tar.xz: File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)
=> Couldn't fetch it - please try to retrieve this
=> port manually into /usr/ports/distfiles/ and try again.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make[7]: stopped in /usr/ports/graphics/png
*** Error code 1
```

I'm stumped on this.

Suggestions, ideas?

Thanks, Dan

Comment: The oldest 1.5.x version of libpng still on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng15/) appears to be 1.5.18.  The current version is 1.6.11.  This suggests that the stashed information about which version of libpng to use is out of date.  You might need to use the Wayback Machine to find the older version.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, this is helpful. I see a package for 1.5.17 here: tp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-stable/graphics/png-1.5.17.tbz   How could I install this manually? Sorry for the newbie question!

Comment: I'm not sure; I'm not a FreeBSD user. I don't immediately recognize the `.tbz` extension.  If I had to guess, it is probably a `.tar.bz2` file (because `.tgz` is an abbreviation for `.tar.gz`).  It might be a compiled version of the software, in which case you install it like you do other compiled software (but I've no idea what mechanism that is on FreeBSD).  Or it might be source, in which case you need to download, configure and build it so that it is pre-built when the `vim` build tries to find it.

Comment: The URL is ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-stable/graphics/png-1.5.17.tbz. As guessed, it is a `bzip2`-compressed `tar` file.  It contains the headers needed to develop/compile with `libpng` and a `.a` and a `.so` library, plus other bits and pieces.  Ignoring issues of permissions (which is a bad idea), you 'could' (which is _very_ different from 'should') install it by running `cd /usr; tar -xf $OLDPWD/png-1.5.17.tbz`.  This would place headers in `/usr/include` and libraries in `/usr/lib` and so on.  But you may know better which tools to use to install software.

Comment: Jonathan, that did the trick. The correct command was cd /usr/local;tar -xf $OLDPWD/png-1.5.17.tbz Many thanks! Am trying to figure out why I can't say you answered this question...

Comment: @Dan please check my answer! You did it wrong! Your package manager doesn't see the "installed" `png` package!

Comment: If you run `portsnap` to update the ports tree, it will install the appropriate files so that libpng-1.5.18 is retrieved, compiled, and installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your **ports tree** should be updated before taking it into use.

Run `portsnap fetch` to fetch the **newest copy** of ports tree.

And for the first time, run `portsnap extract` to rebuild the whole /usr/ports directory.
After that, you can run `portsnap update` instead to do incremental update to /usr/ports .

P.S.
Commands can be concatenated.
Run `portsnap fetch extract` for the first time, and `portsnap fetch update` for daily update.

The version of *png* in the newest ports tree is *1.5.18*

```
xiami@bsd:/usr/ports/graphics/png % head -5 Makefile
# Created by: ache
# $FreeBSD: head/graphics/png/Makefile 349670 2014-03-30 19:44:48Z dinoex $

PORTNAME=       png
PORTVERSION=    1.5.18
```

And make fetch runs well.

```
xiami@bsd:/usr/ports/graphics/png % sudo make fetch
Password:
===>   png-1.5.18 depends on file: /usr/local/sbin/pkg - found
=> libpng-1.5.18.tar.xz doesn't seem to exist in /usr/ports/distfiles/.
=> Attempting to fetch http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng15/1.5.18/libpng-1.5.18.tar.xz
libpng-1.5.18.tar.xz                          100% of  713 kB  960 kBps 00m01s
=> libpng-1.5.18-apng.patch.gz doesn't seem to exist in /usr/ports/distfiles/.
=> Attempting to fetch http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/apng/libpng/libpng15/libpng-1.5.18-apng.patch.gz
libpng-1.5.18-apng.patch.gz                   100% of 9580  B   29 MBps 00m00s
===> Fetching all distfiles required by png-1.5.18 for building
```

Answer (score 4):

You can install packages with `pkg install package_foo`. Check [webpage](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/pkgng-intro.html) (and manuals - of course: [pkg](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=7), [pkg-install](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-install&sektion=8), [pkg-delete](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-delete&sektion=8) and [pkg-add](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-add&sektion=8&n=1)).

If you want install vim from port please `cd` to `/usr/ports/editors/vim` and `make config`. You can choose `CONSOLE` "User interface" (check [freshports/vim](http://www.freshports.org/editors/vim/) "Configuration Options"). After `make config` please use `make install clean`, wait some minutes (or hours - depends on your machine :) ), and done.

More details about port system please check [port documentation](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html) and [man ports](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ports&sektion=7)

One more suggestion: you can use some programs about dealing with ports: the most popular are [portmaster](http://www.freshports.org/ports-mgmt/portmaster/) and [portupgrade](http://www.freshports.org/ports-mgmt/portupgrade/) (I'm using `portmaster`).

Comment: thank you, the pkg install package_foo worked like a breeze, whereas installing it via ports did not. Is the pkg install method recommended in general over using ports? Or do you just use what works in a given situation?

Comment: You can use anything want. pkg are binary - fast, simple. Ports are from source - slow, maybe not simple, but you can configure features. I'm using a mixed system: with pkg and ports.